# VS 2012 C++ How is object able to be Instantiated even though its corresponding #include directive is missing?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, include

I have inherited a Visual Studio C++ project where in a header file (of a template class) an object of another class (a singleton BTW) is able to be instantiated without having its corresponding #include header directive! How is this possible?  This remains so even when I comment out all include directives so there are no implicit incudes in here.  It’s a mystery to me and so I will be grateful for any help. Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry, NathanOliver, but by  Microsoft as your answer are suggesting this is VS bug?  Thanks.

Comment: I am just saying that Microsoft does some weird things.  I don't know if this is detailed anywhere though.

Comment: Are you sure it really is *instantiated*? Invalid template code can compile, if you don't use the invalid function.

Comment: Bo, the code runs successfully w/o the include.  Moreover, when I add the Include I get error messages saying."error C2011: 'CommonParam' : 'class' type redefinition .." and  so its seems to me the header is being included implicitly  but I can't seem to figure out how! FWIW, the singleton class shows up in blue color when typed and Intellisense kicks in even though its header is not included.  Thanks.